# How to avoid "Error: Permission denied to access property 'API'" running locally

Tags: javascript, iframe, permission-denied

I have a webpage with an iframe, I'm loading any website from local storage to that iframe. The host contains the API object which website loaded to iframe wants to access. Both run locally but from different locations. Is there a way to avoid this error? It happens on FF28 and IE10.

Comment: didn't I write "locally"? I want it as off-line tool for my own usage, definitely not for on-line - so how to allow for content run from my hard drive?

Comment: "I'm loading any website to that iframe" made me to think something else ; ).